# How to sort list of lists using sorting key from inner lists?

Tags: python, sorting, ip-address

I have a table that looks like this:

```
list_ip=[
  ['192.168.1.15', 10, 20],
  ['192.168.0.20', 15, 15],
  ['10.0.0.5', 50, 5],
  ['10.0.0.2', 55, 5]]
```

The result should be:

```
[['10.0.0.2', 55, 5],
 ['10.0.0.5', 50, 5],
 ['192.168.0.20',15,15],
 ['192.168.1.15', 10, 20]]
```

When I have just list of IP addresses I can sort them using:

```
import ipaddress 
list_ip=sorted(list_ip, key = ipaddress.IPv4Address)
```

However I cannot figure out how to do it with extra columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import ipaddress 
list_ip = sorted(list_ip, key = lambda x: ipaddress.IPv4Address(x[0]))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I did not know about the `key = lambda x: ipaddress.IPv4Address(x[0])` thing